# Can I get a simple standalone Kafka Producer running through existing CLI without dragging in entire Kafka broker library

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to achieve cronjob which sends a Kafka message once a day. Kafka broker is running on remote instance.

I am currently accomplishing this by installing entire Kafka package, and then having cronjob call a script which look like:

```
less msg.txt | <kafka_path>/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list <AWS_INSTANCE_IP> --topic <topic> --producer.config <property.file>
```

Is it possible to isolate the Jar(s) kafka-console-producer.sh require so I can do this without dragging in rest of the stuff in kafka directory (i.e broker related stuff) into my system? Since they aren't required. Is there some pre-existing solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: By the way, `less` is not the proper command here. Just do `kafka-console-producer... < msg.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you must use JVM solutions, you'd have to build your own tooling with a dependency on `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients`

If you can use other solutions,  `kafkacat` is its own standalone, portable script.